# T-SQL Merge Returning Multiple Results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have two databases that I am in the progress of merging into a single database. Now that they are in a single database, I can link them and use references to improve performance, however first I need to look up the ID from one table, and insert it into the other, as there is currently no foreign key.

The table structure is as follows:

Sighting: Registration, FrameDeliveryDate, RegistrationID

Registrations: ID, RegistrationNo, DeliveryDate

Currently a combination of the registration and delivery date is used to identify records.

I have tried the following statement:

```
MERGE INTO Sightings
USING Registrations
  ON Sightings.Registration = Registrations.RegistrationNo AND Sightings.FrameDeliveryDate = Registrations.DeliveryDate 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
  SET RegistrationID = Registrations.ID;
```

Unfortunately, this fails as sometimes the combination returns more than one record. In such a case I would prefer to ignore linking them, although picking the first record would also be acceptable.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Your sighting table is explicitly non-Relational by virtue of not having any candidate key. Why do you think that relational tools are going to be capable of solving this ISAM problem? The necessity of a candidate key on EVERY table, ie the achievement of First Normal Form, is a prerequisite to the Relational tool kit working properly.

Comment: There are more columns than I posted above, but as they are not relevant  here, I omitted them to keep things simple. One of them is an ID column.

Comment: If possible add sample data and expected result

Comment: Candidate Key and Foreign Key columns are ***always*** relevant, as they define the meaning of your data. Omitting irrelevant attribute columns is fine.

Comment: I think you are mixing up your terminology. The candidate key on Sightings (ID) is not listed here as it is irrelevant. I did however miss off the Foreign Key in the description, which I have now added for clarity, although it was still listed in the SQL statement provided. Regardless, your comment is too confrontational, I suggest toning down your language in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ignore these combinations with more than one match and hence ambiguous values you can use a derived table or CTE.

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT *,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY RegistrationNo, DeliveryDate) AS Cnt
FROM Registrations
), CTE2 AS
(
SELECT *
FROM CTE1
WHERE Cnt = 1
)
    MERGE INTO Sightings
    USING CTE2 Registrations
      ON Sightings.Registration = Registrations.RegistrationNo AND Sightings.FrameDeliveryDate = Registrations.DeliveryDate 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
      SET RegistrationID = Registrations.ID;
```